# Lists of Links in Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, list, web-applications

I am trying to list the links such that it appears as follows:

- Link1
- Link2
- Link3

And then when the user clicks the link, a dialog box appears which loads the content from the dynamically given link into the iframe.

When I click the first link, the dialog that opens shows the correct content. But when I click on the other links (Link2 and Link3), the dialog shows the content of link1 instead of their respective links. I am new to Node.js and so i am not able to figure out what is going wrong.

```
<div class="content">
  <ol>
  {% for ex in array1 %}
    <li>
      <div id="dlg" closed="true" class="easyui-window" title="{{ ex }}" data-options="iconCls:'icon-save'" style="width:850px;height:500px;padding:10px">
        <div class="easyui-tabs" style="width:100%;height:430px">
          <div title="Annotated Example" style="padding:5px;font-size:15px">
            <iframe src="/html/{{ path_to }}/{{ link }}/{{ ex }}" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-link" onclick="$('#dlg').dialog('open')">
        <h5>{{ ex }}</h5>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique. Try this instead...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-link" onclick="$(this).parents('li').find('.easyui-window').dialog('open')">
```

Comment: Although i was also thinking on the same lines, but i did not know how to implement it...The above snippet does not work...the links does not open the dialog